# How to make vue dynamically filter options as we type in the search box?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, element-ui

I want vue to dynamically filter the options available in the search box as we type into it. As of now, it simply displays the whole list of options without any filtering (even if we type).

```
<el-form-item label="Filename" required>
              <el-select
                v-model="queryform.fileUuid"
                :remote-method="getFilenames"
                :loading="loading"
                filterable
                remote
                reserve-keyword
              >
                <el-option
                  v-for="(item, idx) in filenameOptions"
                  :key="idx"
                  :label="item.filename"
                  :value="item.uuid"
                />
              </el-select>
            </el-form-item>
```

filenameOptions is populated and contains objects of the following form:

**{ "filename" : "foo", "uuid" : "bar" }**

The following block of code, which follows the same logic as the previous block, **works as expected :**

```
              <el-select
                v-model="form.project"
                :remote-method="getProjects"
                :loading="loading"
                filterable
                remote
                reserve-keyword
              >
                <el-option
                  v-for="(item, idx) in projectOptions"
                  :key="idx"
                  :label="item.key"
                  :value="item.key"
                />
```

I don't know what's failing. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the `getFilenames` method defined and working similar to the example on the [docs for remote search](https://element.eleme.io/2.13/#/en-US/component/select#remote-search)? Since you have the `:remote-method` attribute defined on the `el-select` element, you need to make sure you provide a valid filter function.

If you just want to filter the option labels based on the input the user is typing into the select element, you might find the [options filtering select element](https://element.eleme.io/2.13/#/en-US/component/select#option-filtering)` cleaner to use.